# Looking to tag a multi-option form with Google Analytics - need JavaScript guidance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I'm trying to track the different form options for this page: http://www.wibitsports.com/formular . Basically I just want to trigger an event for each specific option (out of the 3).

I'm comfortable with setting up the event tracking, the problem is I can't seem to find the HTML to put it on. I think the form's using AJAX - the URL stays the same when I submit.

Where would I find the form code? Ideally I'd like to add event tracking to each form variation's submit button.

If you need any more info I'll do my best to supply it. Clearly in over my head!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("input[type=radio]").live("click" , function() { 
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Wibit Form', 'Radio button clicked', $(this).attr("id")]);
 });
});
```

Meaning: As soon as the document is read attach an event to all radio buttons. Since apparently more options are loaded via ajax use a "live" event (on() ) in more recent jQuery versions) so this event handler will apply to newly created radios as well. Track this as an event (change parameters at your gusto) that stores the id of the clicked radio as label.

Obviously I haven't really tested this with your site, but even if there's an error somewhere in the code it should be enough to get you going.